# How to support 'rpx' in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

rpx is a user-defined format like px in Wechat program.

How to support it on the WebStorm platform?

Comment: Is there a way to create a library binding for webstorm? If Yes, then you should probably do that

Answer (score 0):

1. Install plugin  [[wechat-miniprogram-plugin]](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13396-wechat-mini-program-support), you can find it in WebStorm's plugin market.
2. WebStorm -> Preferences… -> search 'wechat' -> Languages & Frameworks -> Wechat Mini Program -> right side menu，switch【小程序支持】to【启用】-> Apply -> OK -> wait for one or two minutes
3. You can follow this article [《WebStorm 支持微信小程序的 rpx 单位》](https://wufengxue.github.io/2021/05/21/WebStorm-rpx-support.html)

[plugin settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHrql.png)